# Не удается решить сложное уравнение в Python SymPy

Tags: python, математика, sympy, полином, линейная-алгебра

Написал алгоритм, который сначала формирует систему уравнений из `n` неизвестных, решает ее, а решение подставляет в выражение, которое интегрирует.

Далее полученный интеграл приравнивается к нулю и решается как уравнение.

НО если выбрать `n>5`, на последней стадии я не могу получить решение. При этом никакие ошибки не показываются, а программа определяется как запущенная. В таком состоянии оставил часа на три, решение так и не появилось.

Пишу в Spyder.

Похоже проблема в том, что в конечном уравнении есть дроби в знаменателе которых содержится искомая переменная. Как я понял `sympy.solve` не очень дружит с подобными выражениями.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Может как-то можно решить эту проблему?
Код ниже.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
n=int(input("Количество точек: "))
a=0
b=1
nu=sympy.Symbol('nu')
y=sympy.Symbol('y')
dy=np.linspace(a,b,n)
                #блок формирования уравнений
F=sympy.symbols('b0:%d' %n)
Eq15=1
for i in range (n):
    Eq15=(Eq15+F[i])
equations=[sympy.Eq(Eq15,0)] # 1+B1+B2+B3+...=0
J=sympy.symbols('b0:%d' %n)
psi=1
for i in range (n):
    psi=(psi+J[i]*y**(i+2)) # 1+B1*y**2+B2*y**3+B3*y**4+...=0
Eq12=psi.diff(y,y)+nu*psi*(1-y**2)
D = sympy.symbols('b0:%d'%n)
for i in range (n-1):
    Eq12_=Eq12.subs(y,dy[i])
    equations.append(sympy.Eq(Eq12_,0))
                #конец блока
sol=sympy.solve(equations,sympy.symbols('b0:%d'%n))
psi_final=1
for key, value in sol.items(): 
   psi_final=psi_final+sol[key]*(y**((list(sol).index(key))+2))
V120=psi_final.diff(y,y)+nu*psi_final*(1-y**2)
Z=sympy.Eq(sympy.integrate(V120,(y,0,1)))
Z0=sympy.solve(Z,nu)
print(Z0)
```

Если поставить `n=5`, то все решается верно. Если `n=6`, то решение идет до `Z` (можно вывести результат), а `Z0` уже не считает, точнее считает вечность.